# Why can't I connect to Postgres in Docker?

Tags: networking, docker, postgresql

I used [docker-compose](https://github.com/GIScience/openpoiservice/blob/master/docker-compose-with-postgis.yml) from [the Openpoiservice project](https://github.com/GIScience/openpoiservice). 
Both Docker containers were launched successfully.

```bash
kshnkvn@kshnkvn-vb:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
10fafbab73dc        openpoiservice_gunicorn_flask   "/ops_venv/bin/gunic…"   23 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   openpoiservice_gunicorn_flask_1
a66fe5691455        kartoza/postgis:11.0-2.5        "/bin/sh -c /docker-…"   23 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       5432/tcp                 openpoiservice_psql_postgis_db_1
```

But when trying to check the service for functionality,
it could not connect to the database. 
I tried to do it manually:

```bash
kshnkvn@kshnkvn-vb:~$ docker exec -it 10fafbab73dc /bin/bash
root@10fafbab73dc:/deploy/app# psql -h localhost -U gis_admin-gis
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
root@10fafbab73dc:/deploy/app#
```

Strange, checked just in case that the type of container network is the bridge:

```bash
kshnkvn@kshnkvn-vb:~$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                         DRIVER              SCOPE
81001dac99c0        bridge                       bridge              local
8e65fb4ef6f8        host                         host                local
94ce4e1605ef        none                         null                local
a3f48ac3facc        openpoiservice_default       bridge              local
e3d4286df013        openpoiservice_poi_network   bridge              local
```

Checked Postgres launch logs:

```bash
kshnkvn@kshnkvn-vb:~$ docker logs a66fe5691455
Add rule to pg_hba: 0.0.0.0/0
Add rule to pg_hba: replication replicator 
Setup master database
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
2020-02-08 13:50:20.675 UTC [25] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-02-08 13:50:20.683 UTC [25] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-02-08 13:50:20.756 UTC [37] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-08 13:35:17 UTC
2020-02-08 13:50:21.830 UTC [48] postgres@postgres FATAL:  the database system is starting up
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2020-02-08 13:50:22.726 UTC [37] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2020-02-08 13:50:22.730 UTC [37] LOG:  redo starts at 0/21CCC50
2020-02-08 13:50:22.730 UTC [37] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/21CCC88: wanted 24, got 0
2020-02-08 13:50:22.730 UTC [37] LOG:  redo done at 0/21CCC50
2020-02-08 13:50:22.867 UTC [25] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
                              List of databases
   Name    |   Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 gis       | gis_admin | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |           |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |           |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres ready
Setup postgres User:Password
Creating superuser gis_admin
ALTER ROLE
Creating replication user replicator
ALTER ROLE
gis db already exists
                              List of databases
   Name    |   Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 gis       | gis_admin | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |           |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |           |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

2020-02-08 13:50:24.785 UTC [25] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2020-02-08 13:50:24.799 UTC [25] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 58) exited with exit code 1
2020-02-08 13:50:24.801 UTC [53] LOG:  shutting down
2020-02-08 13:50:24.838 UTC [25] LOG:  database system is shut down
Postgres initialisation process completed .... restarting in foreground
2020-02-08 13:50:25.842 UTC [148] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-02-08 13:50:25.842 UTC [148] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-02-08 13:50:25.850 UTC [148] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-02-08 13:50:25.880 UTC [150] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-08 13:50:24 UTC
2020-02-08 13:50:25.887 UTC [148] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

It looks like Postgres started on IP address 0.0.0.0.

I looked at what IPs are used by the Docker `ip addr show` command. 
Tried to reconnect using this IP:

```bash
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
root@10fafbab73dc:/deploy/app# psql -h 172.17.255.255 -U gis_admin-gis
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "172.17.255.255" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What can I try to do to connect the script to the database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## TLDR;

```
psql -h psql_postgis_db -U gis_admin gis
# or
psql -h psql_postgis_db gis gis_admin
```

## Problem with server address

None of the IPs you are trying are actually correct.

- 127.0.0.1 is the localhost address. Since you launch the command from your flask container, there is no posgres service running there.
- 172.17.0.1 is the ip of a docker bridge. This is actually the ip of your docker engine host as seen by your containers on the same bridge. Unless you have a postgres running on your machine and listening to that ip, you'll get no answer (and this would not be the correct postgres server anyway)
- 172.17.255.255 is a network broadcast address for the previous bridge network.

From your start logs we can see that your postgres should be listening correctly. 0.0.0.0 is not actually a real ip: it stands for "any ip configured on this host".

You could look for the ip of your postgres container to contact it (see for example [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host)), but you don't even have to. docker/docker-compose are making this easy for you by mapping container/service names on the same network to their respective IPs automagically. So your db server is reachable using the service name `psql_postgis_db`

## Problem with user and db name

I don't really get what your wrote in your `-U` option to the `psql` command (a mix of user + db name...). Anyway, it should be the username you want to use to connect to the postgres server. From your compose file it is `gis_admin`. Since there is no db with the same name as the user, you need to specify the db name you want to connect to. You either use the `-U` option(`psql -U <user> <db>`) or use positional parameters (`psql <db> <user>`)

Comment: Wow... using the service name instead of any ip or host name is the key.  Thanks.

Comment: What if we run the Postgres container without using the docker-compose file, what will be the host in that case?. Because I can't able to connect using localhost hostname.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the ports parameters to the docker-compose.yml.

Example:

```yaml
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```